# How to deal with screen flickering on Dell XPS

Tags: dell, xps

It is a [well known issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/ccs2r3/xps_15_7590_oled_screen_flickering/) that Dell XPS laptops with OLED screens can cause screen flickering. I used to have severe head aches before fixing the issue in Windows, recently I uninstalled Windows and moved to Ubuntu. After a week of using I've realised that I'm having headaches just like I've used to initially. However, unlike with Windows I have no idea how this can be fixed on Linux-based systems, hence the question.

Comment: How did you fix the issue in Windows?